# JS validation and submission with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, beginner, form, validation

I've got an assignment to do pure JS validation as well as submit with AJAX. Here is the code I've got so far. I'm wondering if I can do away with the whole "reason" bit. That was because it was originally meant to display a list of all the errors, but I've tweaked the code to instead display the errors right by the field.

Basically I want to call up the `validateFormOnSubmit` and just have it go through all the if statements instead of all the separate functions, then if it all passes execute `submitFormAjax`.

The AJAX is currently not working but don't want to troubleshoot that until I've cleaned up the JS code.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justinae/Ehg36/)

**HTML**

```html
<form id="contact" name="contact" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)" action="" method="GET">
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" autofocus />
        <div id="name-error" class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Nickname</label>
        <input placeholder="Nickname" type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" tabindex="2" autofocus />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="3" autofocus />
        <div id="email-error" class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input placeholder="Phone" type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" tabindex="4" autofocus />
        <div id="phone-error" class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>I prefer</label>
        <input type="radio" name="pet" id="Dogs" tabindex="5" autofocus />Dogs
        <input type="radio" name="pet" id="Cats" tabindex="6" autofocus />Cats
        <input type="radio" name="pet" id="Neither" tabindex="7" autofocus />Neither
        <div id="pet-error" class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>My favorite number between 1 and 50</label>
        <input placeholder="Favorite number between 1 and 50" type="text" name="number" id="number" tabindex="8" autofocus />
        <div id="number-error" class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Disclaimer</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="disclaimer" id="disclaimer" tabindex="9" autofocus />I confirm that all the above information is true.
        <div id="disclaimer-error" class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="10">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```javascript
function validateFormOnSubmit(contact) {
    reason = "";
    reason += validateName(contact.name);
    reason += validateEmail(contact.email);
    reason += validatePhone(contact.phone);
    reason += validatePet(contact.pet);
    reason += validateNumber(contact.number);
    reason += validateDisclaimer(contact.disclaimer);

    console.log(reason);
    if (reason.length > 0) {

        return false;
    } else {
        // Show some loading image and submit form
        submitFormAjax();
    }
}

// validate required fields
function validateName(name) {
    var error = "";

    if (name.value.length == 0) {
        name.style.background = 'Red';
        document.getElementById('name-error').innerHTML = "The required field has not been filled in";
        var error = "1";
    } else {
        name.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('name-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
    return error;
}

// validate email as required field and format
function trim(s) {
    return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
}

function validateEmail(email) {
    var error = "";
    var temail = trim(email.value); // value of field with whitespace trimmed off
    var emailFilter = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/;
    var illegalChars = /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/;

    if (email.value == "") {
        email.style.background = 'Red';
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = "Please enter an email address.";
        var error = "2";
    } else if (!emailFilter.test(temail)) { //test email for illegal characters
        email.style.background = 'Red';
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address.";
        var error = "3";
    } else if (email.value.match(illegalChars)) {
        email.style.background = 'Red';
        var error = "4";
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = "Email contains invalid characters.";
    } else {
        email.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
    return error;
}

// validate phone for required and format
function validatePhone(phone) {
    var error = "";
    var stripped = phone.value.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');

    if (phone.value == "") {
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = "Please enter a phone number";
        phone.style.background = 'Red';
        var error = '6';
    } else if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) {
        var error = "5";
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = "The phone number contains illegal characters.";
        phone.style.background = 'Red';
    } else if (stripped.length < 10) {
        var error = "6";
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = "The phone number is too short.";
        phone.style.background = 'Red';
    } else {
        phone.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
    return error;
}

function validatePet(pet) {
    if ((contact.pet[0].checked == false) && (contact.pet[1].checked == false) && (contact.pet[2].checked == false)) {
        document.getElementById('pet-error').innerHTML = "Pet required";
        var error = "2";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('pet-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
    return error;
}

function validateNumber(number) {
    var num = document.forms["contact"]["number"];
    var y = num.value;
    if (!isNaN(y)) {

        //alert('va');

        if (y < 0 || y > 50) {
            //Wrong
            number.style.background = 'Red';
            document.getElementById("number-error").innerHTML = "Must be between 0 and 50.";
            var error = "10";
        } else {
            //Correct
            number.style.background = 'White';
            document.getElementById("number-error").innerHTML = "";
        }
        return error;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("number-error").innerHTML = "Must be a number.";
        var error = "3";
    }
    return error;
}

function validateDisclaimer(disclaimer) {
    var error = "";

    if (document.getElementById("disclaimer").checked === false) {
        document.getElementById('disclaimer-error').innerHTML = "Required";
        var error = "4";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('disclaimer-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
    return error;
}

function submitFormAjax() {
    var xmlhttp= window.XMLHttpRequest ?
        new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            alert("Test Ready State"); // Here is the response
    }

    var name = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
    var nickname = document.getElementById('nickname').innerHTML;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').innerHTML;
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML;
    var pet = document.getElementById('pet').innerHTML;
    var number = document.getElementById('number').innerHTML;
    var disclaimer = document.getElementById('disclaimer').innerHTML;

    xmlhttp.open("GET","form.php?name=" + name + "&nickname" + nickname + "&email=" + email, + "&phone" + phone + "&pet" + pet + "&number" + number + "&disclaimer" + disclaimer, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**PHP**

```php
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$nickname = $_GET['nickname'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
$pet = $_GET['pet'];
$number = $_GET['number'];
$disclaimer = $_GET['disclaimer'];
$from = 'From: Test From'; 
$to = 'euteneier@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
$message = "This is a message.";

if ($_GET['submit']) {               
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $message)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: If you put 0 in the number field, it does not validate. The if statement says "y < 0 || y > 50".

Comment: Good catch @GonzaloNaveira. Thanks. I upvoted the comment.

Answer (score 4):

From a once over:

- You are repeating `.style.background = 'Red';` and `.style.background = 'White';` a ton, what if suddenly all these fields also have to get bold. I would suggest a function like `highlightField` that does the setting of the style:

  ```
  function setHighlight( element , isHighlighted )
  {
    element.style.background = isHighlighted ? 'Red' : 'White';
  }
  ```
- The reason being a number is silly, since you do not do anything with the number, I would simply return booleans and AND these booleans.
- It is considered a better style to have one single `var` statements, with comma separated variables.
- Then, you could change this:

  ```
  function validateEmail(email) {
      var error = "";
      var temail = trim(email.value); // value of field with whitespace trimmed off
      var emailFilter = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/;
      var illegalChars = /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/;

      if (email.value == "") {
          email.style.background = 'Red';
          document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = "Please enter an email address.";
          var error = "2";
      } else if (!emailFilter.test(temail)) { //test email for illegal characters
          email.style.background = 'Red';
          document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address.";
          var error = "3";
      } else if (email.value.match(illegalChars)) {
          email.style.background = 'Red';
          var error = "4";
          document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = "Email contains invalid characters.";
      } else {
          email.style.background = 'White';
          document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = '';
      }
      return error;
  }
  ```

  to

  ```
  function validateEmail(email) {
      var emailFilter  = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/,
          illegalChars = /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/,
          errorMessage = '',
          isValid;

      //Do we have an error ?
      if (email.value == "") {
          errorMessage = "Please enter an email address.";
      } else if (!emailFilter.test(trim(email.value))) { //test for illegal chars
          errorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.";
      } else if (email.value.match(illegalChars)) {
          errorMessage = "Email contains invalid characters.";
      }

      document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = errorMessage;
      isValid = !errorMessage.length;
      setHighlight( email , !isValid );
      return isValid;
  }
  ```

  You could do this for every validation rule.
- You must declare all your variables with `var` so that you do not pollute the global namespace ( I am looking at you, `reason = ""` )
- If all validation functions will return a boolean, than you could rename `reason` to `isValid`:

  ```
  var isValid = validateName(contact.name)     &&
                validateEmail(contact.email)   &&
                validatePhone(contact.phone)   &&
                validatePet(contact.pet)       &&
                validateNumber(contact.number) &&
                validateDisclaimer(contact.disclaimer);
  ```

  obviously the `&&` does not have to be aligned, but it makes my heart beat faster :)
- There would still be the concern that the name `validateXxx` lies a little because it also returns a boolean, but since it also updates the UI and does the validation it would be hard to name this correctly without having a really long name.

Comment: so basically the email functions returns "false" if any of those conditions are met. Where is it returning "true" or valid?

Comment: `||` is a [short-circuit operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If the name is false then it will check the email, if false, then the phone, if false, then the pet, etc...

Comment: @elclanrs Actually I needed more coffee when I wrote that, it should be `&&` since validateXxx returns `true` if the value is valid. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a strong reason for using the `onsubmit` attribute on your `<form>` element, I would suggest attaching the submit action to the form without it. This would work:

```
document.getElementById('contact').onsubmit(function () { return validateFormOnSubmit(this); });
```

Other than that, it might not be a good idea to send the user's email in plain text. You can have an AJAX request use the `POST` method as well as `GET`, which would improve (slightly) the security of personal information.

Comment: This doesn't look right, I think you missed an anonymous function there.

Comment: Whoops! Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

For your JS email validation, I'd consider taking a look at [this regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/3234482).

Also, I'd make sure you have a bit more security on that GET to form.php. That looks like an invitation for spammers!